# How can I link to network files without the use of Chrome addons?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, file-sharing

I'm looking for a method on how I can link to files on a network share without the use of browser plugins.

I'm unable to do

```
file:///server/folder/path.txt
```

due to browser security not allowing it. We're also unable to install plugins network wide, so is there another option to allow for this?

Answer (score 2):

In general, this is disabled because it is a security risk. See also this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254572/cross-browser-link-to-file-on-local-system, and [this one too](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox%5F:%5FIssues%5F:%5FLinks%5Fto%5FLocal%5FPages%5FDon%27t%5FWork).

IMO, the best way to get around this without extensions is to configure the share as an FTP share. Then you can just use
`ftp://server/folder/path.txt` to access those files.

Comment: If its one way, setting up a small web server may be an option too. Could even have basic autentication on it.

Comment: If on windows, can you map a network drive?

Comment: @RyanGriggs No. http://support.microsoft.com/KB/257174 You can setup your webserver to serve files from a remote directory though but this is rife with problems IMO: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207671/EN-US

Comment: I see what you mean.  If the user could copy/paste or type the URL into the address bar, it would work.  But clicking a link would NOT.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek In general, an HTTP server is a fine option and for all practical purposes it is almost the same. The one difference which might come into play is how the files are treated. If someone puts a file on the share which displays in a browser (like an HTML or SWF file), then users will need to go through special steps to download it. Usually, this just means that they'd need to click 'Save As...' but it is just more problems that you don't need. For this reason, FTP has a slight edge IMO. It is true that you can edit your MIME handling on a webserver but its a pain I'd rather avoid